# import webkit2png Python

Tags: python

Quite a simple question here. I want to import webkit2png into another script, but I can't get it to work.

```
import feedparser, webkit2png
d = feedparser.parse('http://example.com/rss')
link = d.entries[0].link
title = d.entries[0].title
webkit2png link
```

This gives me a syntax error on line 5. What do I do wrong?

```
 File "example.py", line 5
    webkit2png link
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`webkit2png` seems to only have a command line interface, so importing the module won't help much, unless you try to replicate the code that is issued in the `main` function in `webkit2png`.

I'd suggest to use the `subprocess` module to call the file directly, e.g.

```
import feedparser
import subprocess

d = feedparser.parse('http://example.com/rss')
link = d.entries[0].link
title = d.entries[0].title

subprocess.call(["webkit2png", link])
```

In case the `webkit2png.py` is in the same directory of your script, replace the `subprocess.call` with

```
subprocess.call(["python", "webkit2png.py", link])
```

Comment: this gives the following error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 8, in <module>
    subprocess.call(["webkit2png", link])
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/subprocess.py", line 443, in call
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/subprocess.py", line 593, in __init__
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/subprocess.py", line 1079, in _execute_child
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: @JacobK How did you install webkit2png? If it's just a python file in the same directory as your script, try: `subprocess.call(["python", "webkit2png.py", link])`.

Comment: That's how I installed it indeed, and this worked! Thanks a lot. Slightly off-topic, but would it be a better idea to install it differently, and if so, why?

Comment: @JacobK I assume you're using MacOS? Not sure how it works there, but e.g. under Linux, if your distribution has a package, it may install the script into your path (say /usr/bin/), so you could execute it independent from your current working directory.

Comment: Sorry to hijack post. I used above example with subprocess.call and I can see image being generated but how to output it to a file?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to start webkit2png as an external program, as it doesn't seem like they have exposed a module interface for the functionality. Try instead:

```
import os;
os.system("webkit2png " + link);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure why it doesn't works a module.. but have a feeling it has to do with `parseopts`.  Try either messing with that… or I can confirm this works…

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call(["python","/bin/webkit2png","http://bReNdAdIcKsOn.com"])
Fetching http://bReNdAdIcKsOn.com ...
... done
0
```

[image: she's half ewish.]